# WordPress function to delay load plugins files after page load

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, performance

How can I load the plugin files after page loads?

My idea is:

1. Get list all of plugins files.
2. using a callback function of buffer with

   ```
   add_action('after_setup_theme', 'buffer_start');
   add_action('shutdown', 'buffer_end');
   ```

to exclude these files then re-add them after page load.

Could you help?

Comment: Doesn’t sound like a good idea to me, I think that is bound to lead to problems in some place or other, at least probably with certain 3rd-party plugins, or “time-critical” client-side stuff. But if you want to try it anyway, then maybe go look into how wp_register_script / wp_enqueue_script and their counterparts work, rather than trying to fiddle with stuff in the output buffer.

Comment: There’s lots of plugins around already to help _aggregate_ multiple such resources into a single one, compress / minify to save on loading times … might make more sense if you looked into some of those first.

Comment: @04FS, Thanks for reply, but I have tried all plugins but no way to improve the site speed so, I think for this idea

Comment: @meno W3 Total Cache has function to defer scripts - works every time. What is your GTmetrix score? Do you have report that you could share?

Comment: @Fresz I had using wp rocket,Hummingbird and Asset CleanUp: Page Speed Booster but still the score is 30% on GTmetrix  and  no way